# Monitor as independent output device

Tags: c++, c, windows, screen, monitor

I want to use a consumer HDMI-projector as output device for a structured light scanner. Currently the patterns are simply displayed in a fullscreen window. The problem is that this conflicts with other parts of the application quiet easily because the window has to manage received window-events and if the main thread pauses the screen isn't updated any longer.

It would be better if I would be able to use the projector independent from the rest of the application. So I can simply create a second thread and display patterns. The "monitor" doesn't need to be available in Windows itself.

Is this somehow possible? My guess is that it would require a custom monitor-driver.

Comment: Why not create a second process which handles the projector window? Whatever happens in the first ("main") process will then not affect the second process, which can go along do what it needs to do by itself.

Comment: This is probably the most obvious solution. Somehow I missed it... I guess it's also the easiest. Thanks!